# How to sort string variable in the order I generated it in the code?

Tags: stata

I have generated a string variable in the following way:

```
gen Category = "none"
replace Category = "Pineapple" if d == 400 | d == 800
replace Category = "Mango" if d == 300 | d == 700
replace Category = "Apple" if d == 200 | d == 600
replace Category = "Orange" if d == 100 | d == 500

sort Category 
by Category, sort: egen Total_volume = sum(volume)

sort  Category
quietly by  Category:  gen dup = cond(_N==1,0,_n)
drop if dup>1
drop dup
```

in the end, I hope to have a output that is sorted by Category, and appear in the order:

```
>     Category    Total_volume
>     Pineapple   2929
>     Mango    5454
>     Apple   1020
>     Orange   5055
```

However, through running the code, some of the observations were dropped so to obtain a single line for a sum of the total volume, what I so far got was in an alphabetical order.

```
>     Category    Total_volume
>     Apple   1020
>     Mango    5454
>     Orange   5055
>     Pineapple   2929
```

How could I adjust so that the output shows in the order I arranged in the current code?

Comment: Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve For example, the definition of `d` is irrelevant to this question. `datex` from SSC (in Stata, type `ssc inst dataex`) is a way of generating self-contained data examples.

Comment: Not the question but the repeated `sort`s are not needed here.

Answer (score 2):

A string variable when sorted is necessarily in alphabetic order, or more generally the order given by the string characters used. If you map to a numeric variable, you can use value label definitions to insist on a different order. See the `help` for `encode` and `label`.

```
label def Category 1 "Pineapple" 2 "Mango" 3 "Apple" 4 "Orange" 
encode Category, gen(Numeric) label(Category)
sort Numeric
```